# How To Install a Private NPM Package Over SSH

Tags: git, github, npm

I have a private repo on GitHub that publishes a package. I added a deployment key to the private repo.

I'm trying to install this repo from elsewhere and running into problems.

First, I created a personal access token with read access under my user account on GitHub. Then, in the repo where I want to install the private repo, I added a .npmrc file that looks like this:

```
strict-ssl=true
@my-org:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=MY_GITHUB_PAT
```

Once that is done, I can successfully install via:

```
npm install @my-org/private-repo
```

However, for various reasons I need to install via ssh. How can this be done? I've tried:

```
npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:my-org/private-repo.git
```

but that only installs the repo, not the package. In my library, the package has build artifacts such as minified files, etc.

Is there a way to install just the package via ssh?

Comment: Do you figure out how to "npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:my-org/private-repo.git"  **I need to install via ssh**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` variable.

```sh
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/<your private key>' npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:my-org/private-repo.git
```

Comment: Unless I'm not mistaken, this only installs the repo, not the package. The package might be different than the repo (e.g. contains build artifacts).

Comment: I think the solution is to make sure to define a "prepare" script in package.json. It can modify the repository (e.g. run tsc or minification) as necessary to make it just like the actual package.

Comment: Did  you figure this out?

Comment: @dwrecked question for you! Do you know how to add or make the process automatically, my idea is to add it, to NPM package.json and my team just has to type npm install and npm will install all dependence, but it doesn't work for me.
 
It works for manual installation.

I read about script configuration on Linux but in windows, it doesn't work!

Comment: Sorry @Daniel I do not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115538/alternative-to-npm/71115681?noredirect=1#comment125797820_71115681

Answer (score -2):

> personal access token

Personal access tokens are used for https access. They are not used by ssh access to github. For ssh access you need to provide your public key to github.

Note that private/public key authentication are optional for ssh. A lot of people use password authentication instead so a lot of ssh installations actually do not generate a private/public key pair for you by default. If you have openssh installed (as most unixen do) you can run the following command to generate your private/public key pair:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Follow the instructions on the command line and it should generate the files needed by github. Sidenote: if you want to use this certificate in automatic scripts I suggest you generate your private key without a passphrase. Otherwise it will prompt you for a passphrase every time you access github.

If you don't change it, ssh-keygen will generate your private key at `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. This is the file you need to upload to github to access your private repo.

> Note: If you are not using openssh then google your ssh software docs for how to generate and access your public key.

To upload your public key login to your account on github, go to your profile (your avatar picture on the top right corner) and click **"settings"**. Then click **"SSH and GPG keys"**.

You will need to repeat all the steps above on all machines you want to access github from as your ssh private/public key pair is specific to the openssh on your machine. You **can** copy your keys to another machine and put it in the `.ssh` folder but this is not a good idea. Separate keys for separate machines means you can easily manage which machines have access to your github account from the github website.

Comment: Fun fact: instead of logging in by password to your servers, after you generate your public/private keys you can run `ssh-copy-id` to install your certificate on the server and then you can login to the server without a password using a better mechanism than passwords