# Alternative to NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

> I am working on a project where we handle private data that we cannot
> risk sharing due to security problems.
>
> We have several packages that we have developed for use in
> applications. We want to control the versions of the packages, but we
> don't have it in private NPM; they are primarily in bitbucket:
>
> We are currently using  to integrate it as a dependency. But we
> wanted to version control those core packages, and we couldn't find a
> suitable replacement for NPM. I don't know if I'm explaining myself
> well, **but I would like to know a good way to simulate something
> similar to NPM using bitbucket.**
>
> **Flow:**
>
> We deploy the module to the instance, then the app... after that, we
> link the module to the app. Using
>
> We run **NPM LINK** and then in the app, we run **NPM LINK NAME**
>
> There is another way to do it?

#### I fixed this problem. That is why I am editing this question!

Leave the idea of ​​starting to open the topic, but that initial idea is only for very specific local tests, but it is not the most elegant!
Saying this: we have to automatically install the private packages, they are hosted on bitbucket.
**The best way I found is a mix between user authentication and ssh for the server environment.**
how it works: is easy this is an example of how the package would look

```
"dependencies": {
"@companyName/example": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:companyName/npm_example.git"
}
```

I literally copied this from bitbucket

- it looks like this when copied
  (git@bitbucket.org:companyName/install_example.git) just add the
  git+ssh:// <- headers

[image: Example of ssh clone]

In this way, if a developer tries to carry out the installation, he has to enter his username and password to be able to install, if he does not have permissions, he cannot install the packages!

Now to use the ssh keys and that everything is clean you must create a private key and a public key.

Then registering the public key on the server with read-only access by default bitbucket allows you to do that cleanly! Go to your repository settings, then access shh register your public key

**Best Part: "SHH access" Pipelines**

```
script:
 - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
 - (umask 077 ; echo $MY_PRIVATE_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
 - cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 - echo "Host bitbucket.org" >> ~/.ssh/config
 - echo " IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> ~/.ssh/config
 - echo " IdentitiesOnly yes" >> ~/.ssh/config
 - echo " UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" >> ~/.ssh/config
 - echo " StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
 - cat ~/.ssh/config
```

**Add tow variables to bitbucket "Repository settings" > "Repository variables"**
[image: Repository variables]

> By using this solution, your team has seamless access, and when you
> deploy, SSH takes care of the authentication, no usernames or
> passwords are exposed, and only the server administrator has access to
> the data. To clean sensitive information from the server watch the
> end!

[image]

**Note that we only clean the data that can be used to clone the repository, and that's it**

***Remember this guide will help you understand the process, use this as an example. There are many things written about this on the internet. I tried to use them and this example was what solved the problem for me. You can put the most elegant and clean scripts, I'm going to leave you the links of everything I read to clarify... Finally, it is complicated to carry out the deployment in bitbucket without having access to that image that is generated. For that, I reproduced that same image in docker which gave me the possibility to enter it and see what was happening. < It is an idea!***

link and credits

[best of the best](https://www.tomspencer.dev/blog/2015/05/20/an-alternative-to-npm-private-modules/)

[hosting private npm modules](https://steemit.com/programming/@donmesswithabeer/use-bitbucket-for-hosting-private-npm-modules)

[Advanced features in Bitbucket Pipelines](https://davistobias.com/articles/advanced-features-in-bitbucket-pipelines/)

[Using GitHub with SSH](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-github-with-ssh-secure-shell/)

[PRIVATE GIT REPO](https://tolotra.com/2018/11/10/how-to-use-private-git-repo-as-npm-package/)

[How can I install an npm package from my bitbucket repository?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-can-I-install-an-npm-package-from-my-bitbucket-repository/qaq-p/752908)

[enter link description here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use dependencies directly from Bitbucket (no need for a private NPM registry). From [Git URLs as Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

> ```
> git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli.git#v1.0.27
> git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli#semver:^5.0
> git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/cli.git
> git://github.com/npm/cli.git#v1.0.27
> ```

Any of these are valid values for dependencies, so you can write in your `package.json`, e.g.:

```
"dependencies": {
  "esd": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.com:youraccount/yourproject#v5.1.0",
  ..
}
```

where `v5.1.0` is a tag.

Comment: That worked for me for the install process via SSH, but I need to automate the installation for Linux and Windows. My idea is to put them as a dependency and when they run 'NPM INSTALL' it will automatically install, Thanks for helping!

Comment: Well it should. That's exactly what `npm install` does: it looks at `dependencies` in the `package.json` and will install any of them that are not yet installed, no matter what the source is (npm registry, git, file..).

Comment: I am trying to install, but SSH access has to be defined and I can't get git to use the private ssh key I sent for authentication!

Comment: that's a different issue. I would try the `git://` protocol and make sure that the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is added to your bitbucket repo ssh keys.

Comment: Excellent I fix it with your suggestion!

Comment: I am using this one git+ssh://git@bitbucket.com:npm:user/repo.git#v1.0.27 with ssh key but npm install does not recognize the ssh and still ask for credentials. Am I missing a configuration?

Comment: @James to use your private key you'll need to add bitbucket.com to your .ssh/config and specify the `IdentityFile` there.

Comment: Hi yes also added it in .ssh but npm still asking credentials. Is there anything I need to add? Thanks

```Host bitbucket.org
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_key```

Comment: bitbucket.org -> bitbucket.com ?

Comment: Hi my mistake i am using bitbucket.org and still the same.

Comment: This comment thread is a poor way to help you. Please create a new question and add all the detail you can (.ssh/config, ls ~/.ssh, package.json)