# NPM install own package from gitlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Here I have a strange problem, when trying to do npm install with package.json that contains:

```
"@me/my-package": "git@gitlab.com:me/my-package.git",
```

Now I can clone the package with ssh, I can even do the similar thing within composer.json that  works:

```
"require": {
   "me/my-package": "dev-main"
},
"repositories": [
   {
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://gitlab.com/me/my-package.git"
   }
]
```

Why does it not work with  npm, and I am on ubuntu 22. It stucks here `sill idealTree buildDeps` around the hour and then displays permission denied

Comment: Share the full error message.

Comment: Its just oermission denied,  check  access rights, nothing else

Comment: Then use `sudo` in front of `npm install`.

Comment: This might be related https://stackoverflow.com/a/61242179/13898633